# Error when uploading file using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: api, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to upload a large file to One Drive using Microsoft Graph API.
Uploading to One Drive works normally, but the file is damaged.
Please help me to solve the problem.

```
public ActionResult UploadLargeFiles(string id, [FromForm]IFormFile files)
    {
        string fileName = files.FileName;
        int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length);

        var uploadProvider = new JObject();
        var res = new JArray();

        var isExistence = _mailService.GetUploadFolder(id);
        if (isExistence != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var createFolder = _mailService.CreateUploadFolder(id);
            if (createFolder != HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            var uploadSessionUrl = _mailService.CreateUploadSession(id, fileName);
            if (uploadSessionUrl != null)
            {
                if (fileSize < 4194304)
                {
                    uploadProvider = _mailService.UploadByteFile(id, uploadSessionUrl, files);
                    res.Add(uploadProvider);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

2. createUploadSession

   ```
    public string CreateUploadSession(string upn, string fileName)
    {
        var uploadSession = _mailGraphService.CreateUploadSession(upn, fileName).Result;
        var sessionResult = new UploadSessionDTO(uploadSession);

        return sessionResult.uploadUrl;
    }

    public async Task<UploadSessionDTO> CreateUploadSession(string upn, string fileName)
    {
        this.InitHttpClient();

        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { item = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" } }, fileSystemInfo = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@odata.type", "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo" } }, name = fileName });
        var toJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
        var content = new StringContent(toJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _client.PostAsync("users/"+ upn + "/drive/root:/MailFiles/" + fileName +":/createUploadSession", content);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return null;

        var strData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic uploadSession = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadSessionDTO>(strData);

        return uploadSession;
    }


    public JObject LargeFileUpload(string upn, string url, IFormFile files)
    {
        var responseCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var jObject = new JObject();

        int idx = 0;
        int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length);
        int fragSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; //4MB => 4 * 1024 * 1024;
        var byteRemaining = fileSize;
        var numFragments = (byteRemaining / fragSize) + 1;

        while (idx < numFragments)
        {
            var chunkSize = fragSize;
            var start = idx * fragSize;
            var end = idx * fragSize + chunkSize - 1;
            var offset = idx * fragSize;

            if (byteRemaining < chunkSize)
            {
                chunkSize = byteRemaining;
                end = fileSize - 1;
            }

            var contentRange = " bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + fileSize;
            byte[] file = new byte[chunkSize];
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", chunkSize.ToString());
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", contentRange);

                var response = client.PutAsync(url, content);
                var strData = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                responseCode = response.Result.StatusCode;

                //업로드 성공
                if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    JObject data = JObject.Parse(strData);
                    string downloadUrl = data["@content.downloadUrl"].ToString();
                    string itemId = data["id"].ToString();

                    //파일 크기 -> kb로 변환
                    fileSize = fileSize / 1000;
                    jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { name = files.Name, id = itemId, url = downloadUrl, size = (double)fileSize });
                }
                //업로드 충돌
                else if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                {
                    var restart = RestartByteFile(upn, url, files.Name);
                    responseCode = restart;
                }
            }
            byteRemaining = byteRemaining - chunkSize;
            idx++;
        }

        if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Created) { return jObject; }
        else return jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { result = "실패" });
    }
   ```

When I checked OneDrive, the file was uploaded normally, and when I downloaded and opened the file, it came out as a damaged file.

I wonder why the file gets corrupted when uploaded, and how to fix it.
If the problem cannot be solved, please let us know that it cannot be solved.

Comment: (1) Have you tried manually upload a file to onedrive and still it works for you?

(2) Outside of your code, have you tried upload the file using MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN? Does it work for you?

Comment: @Dev 
(1) When uploaded manually, the file is uploaded normally. (2) Works outside.

Comment: If it works outside then it's not issue with Graph API call, but i suspect either it may be related to the above code/logic or validate you're correctly setting/passing the necessary headers, correct size of the attachments - similarly what you do with POSTMAN/MS Graph Explorer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Dev (1) It does not matter the size of the attached file. Even small and large files are uploaded and damaged.
(2) How do I pass a file converted to bytes as a header when passing using Postman or MS Graph API?
In the code, I can convert it and pass it right away, but how do I convert it to bytes at random and call it from the graph API?
(3) In the method of direct transfer without creating an upload session, the file is uploaded, but it is damaged. In this case, does an error occur in the part of converting the file to bytes?

Comment: When i tried repro the issue, i failed to see your behavior. Being said that i remember a related thread on this. See you're aware of this and try the code sample available in it to see if it helps you to move ahead - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/493

Comment: @Dev You are not using the SDK.
byte[] file = new byte[files.Length];
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(file);

            var response = await _client.PutAsync("users/" + upn + "/drives/" + driveId + "/root:/HeadMailFiles/" + fileName + ":/content", content);
What I'm curious about is converting the file to bytes when requesting an upload, so I wonder if it gets corrupted when uploading. If so, what format should it be passed in other than bytes?